# aptana studio terminal setup on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, configuration, ide, aptana

I'm just learning ruby on rails and try to configure it to work on windows 7 x64 and aptana studio.

I've installed ruby 1.9.2 with [rails installer](http://railsinstaller.org/) and commands are working from the regular windows command line.

But when I'm trying to use aptana's terminal window I'm getting the following error:

> $ bundle sh.exe": /c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:
>   C:/Projects/railsinstaller/stage/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe: bad
>   interpreter: No such file or directory

How can I make commands to work from terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Git Installed? I believe that must be installed for the Terminal in the studio to work. So first go to:

http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/ and then click on [Git for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=official%20Git).

Go through the steps and once Gitbash is available it may work. If not I have other ideas too.

---

**UPDATE**

Looking at where your `bundle` command is trying to get to, is that really the route? Mine is c:/Ruby192/etc. Try re-installing to that route and get it from the main website ( I know, weird) that is specifically for windows http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ , version 1.9.2-p290. Don't get 1.9.3, bugs on Windows are frequent. I had to go through issues like this too. Then make sure you install the Devkit also. So your steps should be

1. Ruby install
2. Bundle and
3. Devkit

I put my Devkit at C:/Devkit and my Ruby is C:/Ruby192. Windows is pretty corner when it comes to installing Ruby, A complete deleting of everything and re-installing did it for me. Since what that does, if nothing, I got other ideas.

Comment: @Sly So you run something like `bundle install` and it doesn't work correct?

Answer (score 0):

I struggle the same problem on my Windows 7 machine.
I tried to play with my ruby Path in the system settings but I did not succeed. I also used the Railsinstaller. 
You can also use the free Editor "Redcar" or try "Sublime Text".