# Terminal window in eclipse is blank. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, terminal, aptana

When you install and configure RoR on windows and eclipse(Aptana plugin) you would see the terminal window in the eclipse perspective where you would type in various rails/heroku/git commands. One day the window gone blank. I have tried re-installing everything from scratch, looking at PATH variable, installing things in different orders to no avail(The standalone cmd+rails terminal works fine though). Terminal window is just blank. I have been developing using RoR for a semester now with no issues. I have also looked on google but found nothing that describes my problem. If anyone has experienced cold help me with some fresh ideas that would be great!  Ihave also looked at this solution but it didnt fix my problem.. [aptana studio terminal setup on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157117/aptana-studio-terminal-setup-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. Removed git folder from the directory where I was working in (hidden folder) terminal popped back up.